# command not found: spotify-client

Tags: spotify

I tried to install Spotify from this tutorial http://itsfoss.com/install-spotify-ubuntu-1504/ and when I launched it from the terminal is said command not found. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start the app just type `spotify` or `/usr/bin/spotify`

Comment: Thank you, sometimes the most obvious answers are hiding in plain sight!